# ADAL JS for AWS

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

Can ADAL JS be used to resolve CORS issue for the provider hosted app hosted in AWS and installed in SharePoint online? Is it possible to authenticate to SharePoint without using the server-side code in `tokenhelper.cs` file(So that all the computations occur in client-side)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at his post.

It uses ADALjs to authenticate the use. Client side only, no server side code.

http://www.itunity.com/article/started-adaljs-office-365-apis-2144

Comment: Would it be possible for you to extract information from the link and post it in your answer, As links some times breaks.